# JQuery - How to check if input is comming from keyboard or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if input is coming from script or is inputed from keyboard to the textarea?

Is there an easy way to check that?

Im doing the form to send partly auto-generating messages where Im using drop-lists to genearte text and just pasting it to one textarea.

In have a function like:

```
        function refresh() {
            var str2 = "";

            $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
                if (($('textarea', $(this).parent()).val()))
                    str2 += $('textarea', $(this).parent()).val() + " \n";
            });

            $('#Body').val(str2);

        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Think you can combine this https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: You can use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp keyboard key event properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on keyup function like

```
$('#textAreaID').on('keyup',function(){
alert('its keyboard');
//do your stuff
})
```